# How can I insert mod expression returned values from table A into table B?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
select all into result1 from (select mod(employee_id,2) as res from emp
```

Comment: What are `dual` columns?\

Comment: dual is a temporary table which holds temporary data @AliAdlavaran

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle. Don't tag products not involved. (And the answers wont be the same...)

Comment: @avula - you mentioned `dual` somewhere, which shows you are using `oracle`, not `sql-server`. I will edit the **tags** to reflect that. Please pay close attention to those tags: you already received several `sql-server` answers which are not likely to help you in Oracle.

Comment: Then: "insert into... table B" - what does that mean? Does table B exist already? What is its structure (how many columns does it have, what are their names and data types)? Your query suggests it has just one column, of `number` data type - is that so? And what is the point of this exercise - table B will now have a bunch of 0's and 1's, with no other data in the rows. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: I want to know count of the even and odd records by inserting the mod results in to  table B and TABLE B HAS one column with datatype integer @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT 
    *,
    res = e.employee_id % 2
    INTO #dual
FROM
    dbo.emp e;
```

Comment: Then, in plain English, tell us what is it that you want to do. At this point we're all just swinging in the dark.

Comment: The OP is very likely using Oracle, so talking to him in the SQL Server language will probably be useless.

Comment: Yea... The OP changed the tags since answers were posted. It started life with a SQL Server tag, giving the impression that the OP is trying to take what they know in Oracle and translate into t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO @dual (res )
select employee_i % 2 as res FROM emp
```

Comment: The OP is very likely using Oracle, so talking to him in the SQL Server language will probably be useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* INTO dual FROM (SELECT (col % 2) AS resp FROM tbl) A
```

Please note that MOD is **not** available in TSQL.

Comment: The use of MOD, as well as the reference to DUAL, suggests this has nothing to do with TSQL or SQL Server. So then why offer an answer at all?